# Ruby method name with Arithmetic Operators: + - * \ and =, like +=

Tags: ruby, math, methods, operator-keyword, overwrite

I have an ADT (Abstract Data Type) and for that I wrote a method `+(other)`.
`+(other)` returns a new ADT.

If I use it like:

```
adt += otherAdt
```

It will be overwrite `adt`.

But now I want to write a method with name `+=(other)` to change `adt` instead of create a new one.

I try to name my method `+=(other)` and get an error.

My alternative is to name it `plus=(other)`.

I know that if I have two arrays `aArr` and `bArr` and write:

```
aArr += bArr
```

That `aArr` is a new array with the elements of `aArr` and `bArr` and thus has a new Object-ID.

So, is there a way to overwrite `+=`, `-=`, `*=` and `*=` in Ruby?
And if so, how would it look like?

**Edit: I asked a question below @Mladen Jablanović's answer.**

Answer (score 0):

You can not. `a += b` is a shorthand for `a = a + b` and it *always* assigns back to `a`, and you can't redefine assignment, because it is not a method.

Comment: Does this mean `+` is always a method in ruby whereas `=` is either a part of a method name or a standalone for assignment?

Comment: Yes. `=` is part of a method name if left-hand side is something like `object.method`. Otherwise it's simply an assignment.